# no tab completion when using tilda

Tags: cygwin

I am using cygwin on windows machine. Tab completion works as expected in almost all areas, except for when I use tilda (~) to access files/dir under my home dir. When i type 'cd ~/' and hit TAB nothing happens, no completion options are given.

I can type just 'cd' and it will change to my home dir. Also the output of 'echo $HOME' shows my home dir correctly. Finally if i type 'cd ~/' and press ESC then '/' I get completion options... very strange. I have found no solution to this despite searching.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using bash as your shell?